# Treeview click selected row

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

```
   def donorinfo(self, event):
        viewInfo = self.donor_records.focus()
        donordata = self.donor_records.item(viewInfo)
        row = donordata['values']

        self.benefactor_no_entry.set(row[0])
        self.first_name_entry.set(row[1]),
        self.last_name_entry.set(row[2]),
        self.middle_initial_entry.set(row[3]),
        self.contact_number_entry.set(row[4]),
        self.email_add_entry.set(row[5])
```

Hello, can someone help me on how to display the selected database row when clicking it? I don't know why it doesn't work when I use

```
self.donor_records.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.donorinfo)
```

Comment: Are those `self.xxx_xxx_entry` tkinter `Entry` widgets?  If yes, there is no `.set()` function for `Entry` widget.

Comment: what should be the function?

Comment: For `Entry` widget, first use `.delete(0, "end")` to clear the content, then use `.insert("end", row[0])` to set content.

Comment: oh ok i will try that

Comment: i will remove the event in the function?
  def donorinfo(self, event):

Comment: No.  It is required for a event callback.

Comment: oh ok i will try it

Answer (score 1):

`self.donor_records.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.donorinfo)` is the correct syntax.

Comment: You never provided an event or a keysym. Hence, python doesn't know what do bind the table with.

Comment: ohh i see so i will put an event inside def donorinfo

Comment: Is the ```donorinfo``` defined inside the class?

Comment: ah yes but still

Comment: it is inside this class
class Register_As_Donor(tk.Frame):

Answer (score 0):

if you want double click:

```
your_tree.bind("Double-Button-1>", your_func)


selected = your_tree.focus()   # your tree witch you want
values = your_tree.item(selected, text="", values=(.....)) # insert in your entries or something else``
```

Comment: so is it also possible with the database type of value?

Comment: If you get informations from mysql you can double click on a row and put it into the entries for example. but its not only sql.

Comment: you get the informations from your treeview